# Redis 4.0.10: why do we have 0 keys but 9GB dataset size?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, memory, redis, amazon-elasticache

We use ElastiCache from AWS with `redis_version:4.0.10`.
We can see this stats which do not seem to make sense (0 keys, 9G consumed).
Also indeed Redis is full, does not accept writes.

```
hostname.amazonaws.com:6379> memory stats
 1) "peak.allocated"
 2) (integer) 9562806680
 3) "total.allocated"
 4) (integer) 9168470408
 5) "startup.allocated"
 6) (integer) 4197000
 7) "replication.backlog"
 8) (integer) 1048576
 9) "clients.slaves"
10) (integer) 33940
11) "clients.normal"
12) (integer) 117622
13) "aof.buffer"
14) (integer) 0
15) "overhead.total"
16) (integer) 5397138
17) "keys.count"
18) (integer) 0
19) "keys.bytes-per-key"
20) (integer) 0
21) "dataset.bytes"
22) (integer) 9163073270
23) "dataset.percentage"
24) "99.986907958984375"
25) "peak.percentage"
26) "95.876358032226562"
27) "fragmentation"
28) "0.65151870250701904"
```

Comment: I guess you've run `flushall async` or `flushdb async`. So key count has been reset to 0, but the memory is still in the process of releasing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a client running Monitor was still perceived as connected although no client process was anymore. It was gathering commands to list to this client. It had 6G. I killed client on Redis and memory was instantly freed.